# File-level access permission for Gitlab V5 without gitolite

Tags: gitolite, gitlab

Since Gitlab V5 has gotten rid of gitolite, but I still want to use gitolite's useful functions like directory/file-level, branch/tag-level access permission.

Could anyone tell me how to achieve those functionalities within gitlab-shell of Gitlab V5? Is there any configuration file that I can set the rules as I 
can do in gitolite?

Thanks
s

Answer (score 1):

As marked in [issue 47 (How to grant branch level access perms using Gitlab-shell?)](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/issues/47)

> gitlab-shell use API for check permission per branch. gitlab-shell itself does not have any ACL

That means you need:

- first to make sure there is an API you can call in GitLab
- the expose the feature you want through an API in gitlab-shell

But again, gitlab-shell won't implement said feature, it will only call gitlab and return the result (allowed or denied)

You can take example on the introduction of the **fork** feature:

- [gitlab issue 3597](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/3597), depending on
- [gitlab-shell issue 45](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/issues/45)